# Delete bulk (json) files from a csv list in azure repo

Tags: git, azure, powershell, github, azure-devops

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpKsC.png)I have a huge list (~2k) of files (json pipelines) which are not being used anymore and I wanted to delete them from the azure repos.

I have the list in csv format.

git Rm can delete the files from the repo but considering the number of files I have to delete, need an automated approach to read the file names from the csv file and delete the same from repository.

Could anyone have a PowerShell script or any workaround to achieve this quickly? Appreciate your inputs

Comment: `git rm files to delete`. I'm not sure what your question is. If you need to rewrite history, there are many questions&answers on this site already

Comment: You have to show the format of your CSV file. Does it have to be PowerShell or would bash work too? Bash comes pre-installed with Git for Windows.

Comment: @knittl Thanks for the response. I have attached the image in the question. The format of the file is a simple list. any approach would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a file with one path per line (and no path contains LF or CR characters), then `git rm` already supports this exact behavior via the [`--pathspec-from-file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm#Documentation/git-rm.txt---pathspec-from-fileltfilegt) option:

> ##### `--pathspec-from-file=<file>`
>
> Pathspec is passed in `<file>` instead of commandline args. If `<file>` is exactly `-` then standard input is used. Pathspec elements are separated by LF or CR/LF. Pathspec elements can be quoted as explained for the configuration variable `core.quotePath` (see git-config[1]). See also `--pathspec-file-nul` and global `--literal-pathspecs`.

To use:

```
git rm --pathspec-from-file=filelist.txt
```

This should work regardless of shell. If you have a POSIX-compatible shell, such as `sh` or `bash`, then a while loop could be used instead (`while IFS= read -r path; do git rm -- "$path"; done < filelist.txt`).